# Get current process id when using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using `concurent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` has a *high level* API to multiprocessing.

I want to identify the current process in the worker functions.

With the *low level* API `multiprocessing` I can do it like this.

```
import multiprocessing
  
def worker():
    print(multiprocessing.current_process())
```

Is there a `current_process()` pendant when using workers with the `ProcessPoolExecutor()`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "pendant." But either `import os; print(os.getpid())` or `import multiprocessing; print(multiprocessing.current_process().pid) will work`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each execution happens in a separate process, you can simply do

```
import os
  
def worker():
  # Get the process ID of the current process
  pid = os.getpid()
  ..
  .. do something with pid
```

For example,

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import os
import time

def task():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Executing on Process {}".format(os.getpid()))

def main():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        for i in range(3):
            executor.submit(task)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

➜ python3.9 so.py
Executing on Process 71137
Executing on Process 71136
Executing on Process 71138
```

Note that if the task in hand is small and executed fast enough, your pid might stay the same. Try it out by removing the time.sleep call from my example.

Comment: Of note: the PID staying the same is the result of the task taking significantly less time than starting up a new process. The Pool will start 3 workers, and the first to complete "booting up" is then able to complete the three tasks before the others are finished "booting up".